# Render multilevel component link fields in DWT

Tags: templating, dwt

I am writing a DWT TBB to get field value of multi level component link field. I have a component having componentlink field("list") and in those component i have another component link field("management"). Both componentLink fields are multivalued. I need to iterate those fields. But its not rendering the desired output may be because of misinterpretation of TemplateRepeatIndex.  Did someone encounter this scenario.

```
Title of the component : @@title@@
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="list" -->   
    <li class="accordion-item">
    <a href="#" class="accordion-link">@@Get("Fields.list[${TemplateRepeatIndex}].title")@@</a>
    <div class="board-members">
            <!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="@@Get("Fields.list[${TemplateRepeatIndex}].management")@@" -->   
                <div class="member">
                    <h4>@@Get("Fields.list.management[${TemplateRepeatIndex}].designation")@@</h4>
                    <p class="intro">@@Get("Fields.list.management[${TemplateRepeatIndex}].intro")@@</p>
                    @@Get("Fields.member[${TemplateRepeatIndex}].description")@@    
                </div>
            <!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->   
    </div>  
    </li>

<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you're using the DGX?

Comment: @NickoliRoussakov yes i am using DGX and its working very fine.

Answer (score 4):

You are right; If there is a loop in a loop the counters are not stored of the outer loop(s);

```
TemplateRepeatCount
TemplateRepeatIndex
```

If you want to resolve this you can build a [Custom Function](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_EFD94BC0585D4186A13F7F3C3B6F47EA) (login required, Tridion 2011 documentation)

Or switch to the [Razor Mediator](https://code.google.com/p/razor-mediator-4-tridion/) that does support this kind of functionality out of the box :)

Comment: Or build a simple c# TBB to fetch the field values and place them on the package, or use the nested component template technique as described here: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/the-solution-to-hardcoding-component-template-ids-in-nested-component-presentations

Comment: Can we use XSLT TBB ?? if yes , can you please provide some thoughts.

Comment: Sure, you can use `document()` in XSLT to reference other components. See an [example from Chris Summers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10249349/395495).